# SUMIFS or IF lookupin Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010, sumifs

I currently have the formula which `=SUMIF(AE12,">0",AD12)` returns the value if the figure is greater than a zero, I'm trying to add in an additional SUMIF which states if its greater than zero return AC12 .

I've tried `=SUMIF(AE12,">0",AD12), SUMIF(AE12,"<0",AE12)` but it errors, everything i do errors actaully!

Also tried `=SUMIFS(AE12,">0",AD12,"<0",AB12)`

Cant get this to work at all!

Comment: Are you aware of the 'SUMIFS' function?

Comment: yeah but it tells me i'm not supplying enough criteria? SO id something like =SUMIFS(AE12, ">" & 0, AE12, "< " & 0,AB12)  but it errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this slight modification

`=SUMIFS(AB12, AE12, ">" & 0, AE12, "<" & 0)`

Note that the `SUMIFS` signature is different than `SUMIF`.

That is...

`SUMIFS` expects (`sum_range`, `criteria_range1`, `criteria1`, `critera_range2`, `criteria2`, etc..)

whereas

`SUMIF` expects (`range`, `criteria`, `[sum_range]`)

Comment: Sorry, im trying to return one value in a specific cell. So like =SUMIFS(AE12, ">" & 0, AE12, "< " & 0,AB12)

Comment: @Gavlaa Updated my answer to match your more explicit logic